# Replace src of the image in description

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have a string coming from database as given below. I want to change the img src in the text below to be `./upload-files/<filename>` instead of `../upload-files/<filename>`.

```
<p><span style="text-decoration: line-through;">
<img style="float: left; margin-left: 5px; margin-right: 5px;" src="../upload-files/teddybear.jpg">
</span></p>
```

So basically I want image to use the current directory instead of the parent directory `../`
How can i do this? Is preg_replace the right tool here?

Comment: `str_replace('src="..', 'src="', $string);`

Comment: with regex, `preg_replace('/^\.\./', '', $img_url)`, where $img_url is your image path. if you don't have the same `..` more then once in your string, use `str_replace` instead.

Comment: It may exist more than once in the description text... :(

Comment: @machineaddict i tried your way but still the url comes with the preceeing "../" ...

Comment: You are probably not using it right. Check my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an intermediary variable to store your image you can use:

```
$img_url = '../upload-files/teddybear.jpg';

$img_url = print_r(preg_replace('/^\.\./', '.', $img_url));

<p><span style="text-decoration: line-through;">
<img style="float: left; margin-left: 5px; margin-right: 5px;" src="<?php echo $img_url;?>">
</span></p>
```

if you are trying to replace `../` inside a bunch of html, use this:

```
$my_html = '<p><span style="text-decoration: line-through;">
<img style="float: left; margin-left: 5px; margin-right: 5px;" src="../upload-files/teddybear.jpg">
</span></p>';

print_r(preg_replace('/"\.\./', '".', $my_html));
```